# jquery calendar doesn't show with royal slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

Im working on a website for a hotel I have the reservation box in the same page as the royal slider plug-in both have their respective files

-This is for the hotel box datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js//dtpicker/jquery.ui.datepicker-<?=$langauge_selcted?>.js"></script>
```

-This is for the slider

```
<script src="royalslider/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script>
<script src="royalslider/jquery.royalslider.min.js"> </script>
<link href="royalslider/royalslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="royalslider/skins/minimal-white/rs-minimal-white.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I leave it like that the datepicker doesn't show when I press the calendar button

When I remove

```
<script src="royalslider/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script>
```

The slider stops working but the datepicker works fine

Help :S

Comment: youre loading 2 instances of jquery

Comment: I know but when I remove one the other stops working